# Was Argus Filch's cat, Mrs. Norris, a transmogrified human or an Animagus?

Tags: harry-potter

I found guesses on this topic on other questions, but never anything definitive or dealing directly / solely with this question. Filch and Mrs. Norris communicate and he seems fond of her. Is it possible she was/is a woman and they have a deeper relationship than is presented? I do not mean this in a flippant or gross way, but from the start it seemed to me like something strange (not necessarily untoward) was going on. I do not remember this being directly addressed in the books or the films, but nor was Dumbledore being gay, so that does not mean it wasn't something hinted or clued about. It may have been and I forgot, and my books are in storage at the moment.

I read elsewhere on here that on Pottermore JKR calls Mrs Norris "an animal" rather than "a magical creature." Does that mean she only said animal and someone read into that comment or did she specify she was not a magical creature? The search engine would not help me locate the reference on the site. Could that be a red herring if she *had* been a person at one time and has been changed?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'll quote Rowling here:

Question:

> Mrs. Norris is an unregistered Animagus

Rowling's answer:

> No, she's just an intelligent (and unpleasant) cat.

I found this here: http://web.archive.org/web/20110623023949/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/rumours.cfm

Answer (score 4):

Argus Filch's cat Mrs. Norris is just an ordinary cat. It has been stated clearly by J. K. Rowling as described in the following [Wiki](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Mrs_Norris#Behind_the_scenes):

Also cats have keen senses which justifies the fact that Mrs. Norris is used by Filch to track down mischievous students and Peeves the poltergeist.

Answer (score 2):

While Mrs. Norris is the one animal where we see a pronounced connection between her and her person, to some extend all of the witches and wizards are shown to have more of a connection with their animals than your usual house pet. These creatures are familiars which while still animals have always been represented as being something more. Think of Hedwig sacrificing herself for Harry and the way Crookshanks specifically targeted Ron's rat, the evil Peter Petigrew in hiding. Also think of the way all the owls are used to deliver mail.