# How old is Mrs. Norris?

Tags: harry-potter, age

Is it established anywhere how old Mrs. Norris is?

Reading [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/165810/36769) about the Marauders' Map made me wonder how old Filch's cat is at the time of the books. Granted, it seems Mrs. Norris was well cared for and it's possible she may have had some magical intervention to help prolong her life (e.g. we know she was eventually healed (for lack of a better term) after the reflected basilisk gaze petrified her), but it seems she has likely had an extraordinarily long life for a house cat.

If James and his buddies made the map while they were at Hogwarts and made a point of tracking the cat, then she would have to be at least 16 years old when Harry received the map. If the speculation in that answer is correct, it seems likely the kitty is significantly older, as she would have annoyed the Marauders enough to get them to have the map track her. While cats have been known to live to be more than 30 years old, 16 or 17 is pretty old, even for well cared for house cats.

Comment: Dumbledore was, what, 125 when he died?  Why shouldn't Mrs. Norris live to 35 or 40?  We can count up she was at least in her mid-20s by the time Harry left Hogwarts -- if she could live as much past the normal cat maximum as Dumbledore did past the Muggle maximum, she might make it to 35 or more.

Comment: the problem with that answer is they don't have any evidence mrs. norris was at hogwarts at the same time as James et all

Comment: @ZeissIkon: It is established throughout the series that wizards live longer lives than muggles (assuming a death of natural causes). However, Mrs. Norris is a normal house cat; living into her 20's would be exceptional (my family has had cats almost my whole life, and I don't think any have made it past 18 or 19 (and I'm old enough that I don't want to say how old I am)).

Comment: @WraithLeader; Yes, but it also seems that no other animals are tracked by the map. Also, [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/38344/36769) establishes that the map was made with a spell to track humans and human-like beings, making one think that special effort was made to track the cat.

Comment: @GreenMatt The map was in the possession of the Weasley twins though before Harry had it. I would not be surprised if they figured out a way to add Mrs. Norris. Nothing tells us if they did any changes and if they were that capable. But they had to experiment with it to figure out how it works. Why not adding the Mrs. Norris?

Comment: Edit, a few relevant links: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/40136/was-argus-filchs-cat-mrs-norris-a-transmogrified-human-or-an-animagus  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/38336/what-kind-of-beings-are-shown-by-the-marauders-map

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Most *probably* not old enough to be around with the Marauders

J.K. Rowling has said that Mrs Norris is an ordinary cat, not an animagus, and not part Kneazle like Crookshanks.

> **Rumour: Mrs. Norris is an unregistered Animagus**
>
> **J.K. Rowling:** *No, she's just an intelligent (and unpleasant) cat.*
> <sub>([old jkrowling.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20110430144944/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/rumours_view.cfm?id=40))</sub>
>
> **Who would win in a fight, Mrs. Norris or Crookshanks?**
>
> **J.K. Rowling:** *It would be brutal and very close, but Crookshanks' Kneazle ancestry would bring him out on top.*
> <sub>([Twitter](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/644197707939213312))</sub>

As you said, normal cats do not live very long. Wikipedia puts the average cat life expectancy at under ten years.

> The average lifespan of pet cats has risen in recent years. In the early 1980s, it was about seven years, **rising to 9.4 years in 1995**, and 12–15 years in 2014. However, cats have been reported as surviving into their 30s, with the oldest known cat, Creme Puff, dying at a verified age of 38.
> <sub>([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat#Health))</sub>

Mrs Norris has been alive for some time before book one (she's implied to have been around for some time), and is still alive during the Battle of Hogwarts (Harry observes her attacking owls).

In order to have been around before Filch confiscated the Map from the Marauders, she would need to be at least nineteen years old when we last see her. This is possible, but very unlikely.

**She was most likely born a few years before the series starts, but could have been a bit older.**

Comment: This is a perfect example of a "*We don't know question*" your logic is backed up and you've gone into sufficient detail. Excellently done.

Answer (score 1):

## We don't know.

I just scanned through the books, looking for any mention of her age. Nope... nothing.

A Google search for `site:pottermore.com "Mrs Norris"` does not reveal anything about her age. Neither does anything on accio quote.

I could not find anything on her Twitter.

Wikipedia doesn't have any information on her age either. I even checked the Harry Potter wikia - nothing. Sorry, but we just don't know.