# Would a Muggle show up on the Marauder's Map?

Tags: harry-potter, magic

Would a non-magical individual (i.e a Muggle or a Squib) show up on the Marauder's Map? I think I'm wondering moreso about Muggles really, and how the Marauder's Map would deal with a Muggle who managed to access the castle.

In *Goblet of Fire* we learned that Hogwarts is highly protected from discovery by Muggles by various charms, spells, and hexes; this suggests Hogwarts is basically impossible to outright find if one were to actually go looking for it. We know this much, so let's set that aside. **If a Muggle somehow *accidentally* breached Hogwarts' protective wards and actually stumbled onto the Hogwarts grounds or into the castle itself, would he or she show up on the Marauder's Map? Why or why not?**

<sub>Just as a general FYI, I still dislike the *Harry Potter* wikia as a reference.</sub>

Comment: [This image](https://media.shellypalmer.com/wp-content/images/2014/07/marauders-map.jpg) indicates that Squibs at least show up on the map.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/38336/what-kind-of-beings-are-shown-by-the-marauders-map

Comment: Edit on the accepted answer says the map is supposed to show humans or anything humanoid. If that is correct and since muggles are humans they should show up

Answer (score 24, accepted):

We see Harry spotting Filch and his cat on the map multiple times.

This is as close as we get to a "non magical" creature on the map: Filch is a squib and his cat -although it seems to be more intelligent and knowing than normal cats- is never said to have magical properties.

Rowling on the contrary clearly emphasised, that Mrs. Norris is a normal cat:

> No, she's just an intelligent (and unpleasant) cat.

as you can read [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/40136/was-argus-filchs-cat-mrs-norris-a-transmogrified-human-or-an-animagus)

Here are two examples of Harry spotting them both:

> A map of Hogwarts appeared on the blank surface of the parchment. Tiny black moving dots,
> labeled with names, showed where various people were.
> “**Filch** is on the second floor,” said Harry, holding the map close to his eyes, “and **Mrs. Norris** is on the fourth.”
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 18: Dumbledore’s Army</sub>

> then, moving slowly and
> cautiously, they proceeded down the many staircases, pausing at intervals to check on the map for signs of **Filch** or **Mrs. Norris**.
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 20: Hagrid’s Tale</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm more interested if a Muggle would show up on the map, what with the lack of magic and all.  :)

Comment: I‘d say: yes he would, no magic required to be on the map... but I do not know of anything that proves this..,

Comment: For a Muggle to be invisible on the map, they have to be transparent to magic. Although this concept exists in some fantasy worlds (eg. Pristinely ungifted in the Sword Of Truth Universe), Muggles are not that in Potterverse. Otherwise, Voldemort would be unable to kill a Muggle. So the map sees them, as well as 'Magic' people. The mention of Filch and Mrs. Norris is a sufficient proof.

Comment: @TimSparrow - Good reasoning. I have always thought that Muggles would show up on the map, but thought I would posit it anyway. :)

Answer (score -2):

I don't believe Muggles would show up because as someone said above Mrs. Norris is the only non-magical creature to show up on the map. I however believe that Filch and Mrs. Norris are poltergeists, not a staff member that Dumbledore hired.

One question needs answering to be able to find out if Muggles will show up. How does the map work? Not only did it show people in the generation the Marauders made it but generations to come. My best guess is it uses the quill of The Quill of Acceptance and the Book of Admittance. It traces the names from them and tells you where they are. Muggles would not be in The Book of Admittance so they would not show up.

Comment: Hi Liz! thanks for answering! Unfortunately, your answer doesn't have any sources. Would you like to edit some in? Please check out our welcome tour before writing more answers (which we eagerly await.)